# Unity 5 - UI mask working incorrect (as 2D Rect Mask) on android HTC One

Tags: android, scrollview, unity-game-engine, mask

I have created simple scene for test in Unity 5.4.2f1 and added scroll rect with mask sprite. 
[image: Scroll rect with image mask in Unity 5.4.2f1]

Sprite settings are these:

[image: UI mask sprite import setting.]

In the Unity Editor and on all my android devices, such as Samsung Galaxy Tab Pro and Nexus 5X are working perfectly:
[image: UI scroll view with image mask on Samsung Galaxy Pro (Android 4.4.2)]

But on my HTC One (Android 5.0.2) it's working not correctly. Mask script is behaving like Rect Mask 2D script:
[image]

Comment: Very detailed question. I think you should experiment with the Texture settings to see if maybe that is the problem. The two important settings I would modify is the **Max Size** and the **Format**. I suggest you lower the **Max Size** and test each time. As for your Samsung Galaxy Tab Pro and Nexus 5X , what is their Android version?

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply @Programmer . I have tried a lot of setting, but still same result. Android version of Samsung Galaxy Tab Pro is 4.4.2 and Nexus 5X is 7.0.